# Ethernet not working on windows 7

Tags: networking

I have a DELL laptop which comes with both a wirless and ethernet adpater. Yesterday, after browsing I shut it down and  when I rebooted it refused to connect to the internet using wireless. (The wireless router seems to be working fine since I have another computer which connects to the internet without any problem). The first thing I did was to ping my router:
`ping 192.168.1.1` and the dreaded request timed out message appeared.  I realized I am not even connected to the local network and as usual the windows troubleshoot gave me this message - `The connection between your access point, router, or cable modem and the internet is broken`. Then back to squareone I decided to give resetting my wireless card a try:

```
netsh winsock reset 
netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
```

and rebooted the laptop. But to no avail- The wirless connection still refused to work. So then I connected the ethernet cable and tried to see if that would work -But it didnt. It still could not ping my network. So what exactly should  I do next to get the internet working on the computer.
The adapter properties are `obtain an ip address automatically`. When i type in ipconfig it shows me that the computer has an ip address of 192.168.1.102 assigned to it.

Comment: so you have a 192.168.1.102 wired and you can not ping your router? 192.168.1.1?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: What happens when you try to connect to the network? Is it detected in your list of wireless networks? If so, what happens when you double-click on it?

Comment: Yep. It is detected. It shows me it is connected but with an yellow exclamation. Anyway, the system restore solved the issue

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

go to

> Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks

I would remove the wireless network properties and create a new one from scratch.

Comment: OKay, I  used restore point which had been created previously and it seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Using a restore point seemed to solve the issue.